# Anyway to change the "Name", or "Initiator", or add new tabs in Chrome Dev Tool's Network view?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, post, google-chrome-devtools

I was wondering if there was anyway to change the name or initiator columns in the Network Tab in Chrome's Dev Tools.

The issue is that, currently I'm making a web app, and it makes tons of POST calls using jQuery. that's all fine and dandy, however, when I have 10+ calls, obviously the Network tab gets flooded with POST calls.

All calls are to the same PHP script, thus the Name column is all the same. Also, since I'm using jQuery, the initiator is set to jQuery. I was wondering if there was any way to customize this view so that I know what script is calling the POST without having to open each call and see it's properties.

It'd even be nice to see maybe a truncated version of values sent right in the list view. This way I can just look at each call and know exactly what function or script called it, or at least have a better idea, rather than 10+ entries of Name: " xxx.php".

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom columns that show you the values of response headers by right clicking on the table header and selecting Response Headers > Manage Header Columns:

[image: manage header columns]

You can also hide columns via this right-click menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a query to the url you are posting to, with information about what function you are calling.

Example:
If you are posting to `https://myserver.com/api` it is the last part `api` that will be displayed as the name in the network tab.

So you can extend that url with `https://myserver.com/api?whatever` and you will see that in the network tab name. The back end server can and will just ignore that extra query in the url.